# On the bijectivity of $f:\mathcal P(E)\to\mathcal P(A)\times \mathcal P(B); X\mapsto (X\cap A, X\cap B)$ with $A,B\subset E$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Can anyone clarify this question, I don't get it?

> Let $E$ be a set, $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of $E$.
>   Consider the map $f: \mathcal P(E) \to\mathcal P(A) \times\mathcal P(B)$ defined by
>
> $$f(X) := (X \cap A, X \cap B)$$
>
> 1. (a) Prove that if there exists a subset $X\subset E$ such that $X \cap A = A$ and $X \cap B = \emptyset$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
>      (b) Deduce that if $f$ is surjective, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
>      (c) Prove that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $f$ is surjective.
> 2. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if $A \cup B = E$.
> 3. When $f$ is bijective, define its inverse $f^{−1}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
To get you started with the proofs note the following:

- $A\cap B = B \Rightarrow B\subset A$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset \Rightarrow B\subset A^C$.
- If $X\cap A = A, X\cap B = \emptyset$, then $f(X) = (A,\emptyset)$.
- If $A\cup B \subsetneq E$ and $C\subset E\setminus (A\cup B) \neq \emptyset$, then $f(X) = f(X\cup C)$.
- You should be able to guess $f^{-1}$. There is only one sensible candiate, just verify it.